# Generating a proper finite difference scheme

Tags: physics, numerical-analysis-of-pde, finite-differences

I have recently started studying the finite difference schemes for numerical analysis. While I can now calculate difference schemes fairly easily for simple equations, I've recently come across a problem while studying this research paper on the [pulsar wind nebula](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-637X/715/2/1248/pdf) (Eq 12) that I wanted to try and estimate numerically.

The equation is as follows,

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}N(\gamma, t) = -\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \gamma}\left[\dot{\gamma}(\gamma, t)N(\gamma, t)\right] + Q_{inj}(\gamma, t)$

I have derived the formulae for $\dot{\gamma}$, $Q_{inj}(\gamma, t)$ and other relevant quantities as well.

Here's what I'm not understanding on how to estimate the factor $N(\gamma, t)$. I can take an array of $\gamma$ and try to estimate boundary conditions for $\dot{\gamma}(\gamma, t)$, and $Q_{int}(\gamma, t)$ respectively. I can set $t=1$ to get the initial condition since $t=0$ gives undetermined value. But how would I do the same for $N(\gamma, t)$. There is not expression given for $N(\gamma, t)$ in the paper either.

If I try to solve the PDE manually, I can

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}N(\gamma, t) = -\dot{\gamma}(\gamma, t)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \gamma}N(\gamma, t) - N(\gamma, t)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \gamma}\dot{\gamma}(\gamma, t) + Q_{int}(\gamma, t)$

For constructing the FTFS shceme for this I was considering $U = N(\gamma, t)$, $V = \dot{\gamma}(\gamma, t)$ and $W = Q_{int}(\gamma, t)$. But when I work throught the scheme, I cannot separate these two values.

Any help or guidance will be much appreciated.